# How to get information from database to React site

Tags: database, reactjs

I'm build a website using ReactJs and Node. In administrator's panel I want to build table with users' names and mails. But... I don't know how to get users' information from database.

I use local database localhost:8080/user/.

In table I have information - name and email of currently logged in administrator.

//my table

```
<table border = "4" cellpadding = "10">
   <tr><td>UserName</td><td>E-mail</td></tr>
   <tr><td>{isAuthenticated().user.name}</td><td>{isAuthenticated().user.email}</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to build table on site with users' information, who registered on my  website, no only information with currently logged on administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fetch API to get those data from the server, and call the method `fetchData()` via life cycle hook `componentWillMount()` to send request to the server before the page is mounted, you can then iterate each of the elements in the data using `map()` method in the table element.

```
export default class myApp extends React.Component  {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: []
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
       this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData(){
      fetch('https://localhost:8080/user/')
       .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseToJson) => {
            this.setState({ data: responseToJson })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
     }

     render(){
       const { data } = this.state.data
       return(
         <div>
          {data.map((item, index) => {
           return(
            <div key={index}>
              <table border="4" cellpadding="10">
                 <tr><td>UserName</td><td>E-mail</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>{data.name}</td><td>{data.email}</td></tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            )
           })}
          </div>
        );
      }
   }
```